# Field value not updating

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, data-binding, binding, flash-cs5

I have genuinely, genuinely looked ALL over the web for a basic scoring system and can't find one that actually works. Maybe it's just me/ my game but nothing works.
I'm trying to do it with a dynamic text box. So i've got a starting score.
But when i put:     "Score = Score + 10;"
Nothing happens. So yeah, any help please. I'm gonna put up most of the game code, to see if it's something else, and there's only ~ 30 lines...I want it so when the two objects collide the score goes up. THANKS
Oh and I embedded the text, after flash told me to. Hence the first line ↓.

```
import flash.text.*;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.text.TextField;

var pressedKeys:Object = {}; 

// BASIC KEYBOARD MOVEMENT - Took it out as it is almost defs irrelevant.


var Score = 10 
var myText:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(myText);
myText.text = ("Score:"+ Score);
myText.textColor = 0xFF0000;
myText.border = true;
myText.height = 20;
myText.x = 4;
myText.y = 4;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitTest)
function hitTest(e:Event):void
{
    if(Hero_Mc.hitTestObject(Enemy_mc)&& (Enemy_mc.width<Hero_Mc.width))
   {
      Hero_Mc.width=Hero_Mc.width +4;
      Hero_Mc.height=Hero_Mc.height +4;
      Enemy_mc.stop();
        removeChild(Enemy_mc);
        addChild(Enemy_mc);
        Enemy_mc.x= Math.floor(Math.random()*500);
        Enemy_mc.y= Math.floor(Math.random()*350);
        Score = Score + 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing changes because `myText.text` only receives the value of `Score`, not the actual reference. You can either use `BindingUtils`. Or, you can change the following line:

```
var Score = 10;
```

to

```
private var _score = 10;
protected function set Score(value:Number):void {
    _score = value;
    //Now, whenever you set Score to anything, it also sets the text on myText.
    myText.text = ("Score:"+ Score);
}

protected function get Score():Number {
    return _score;
}
```

---

Also, I agree with citizen. ActionScript convention is to use lowercase variables and `_prefixed` for private vars.

Comment: GENIUS, it works. Thanks a bunch. Ahh thanks for the heads up, i only started AS3 like a week ago, after only a little of HTML5. Self-taught and that. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer. It helps your reputation. And good luck with as3!

Answer (score 0):

This is a little better syntax:

```
var score:Number = 10;
score += 10;
```

Is that if statement evaluating true?

Comment: yes it is, sorry should have said, i was trying to make a game like fishy... :P but yes that's where the score increase would come from

Comment: try my syntax instead, might help. sometimes flash is weird like that

Comment: I did...it didn't. The other one did though. BUT thanks, it 's the thought that counts :P